# Time complexity of the algorithm by counting the comparisons and we need to give a big o estimate

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, discrete-mathematics

Time complexity of the algorithm by counting the comparisons and we need to give a big o estimate
How can we do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i := 1 to m                // Loop 1
    for j:= 1 to n             // Loop 2
        cij := 0
        for q := 1 to k        // Loop 3
            cij := cij + aiqbqj
return C
```

Note that within loop 2, there are exactly `k + 1` assignments, so while `j` loops from `1` to `n`, there are in total `n * (k + 1)` assignments.

Adding on top of that, while `i` loops from `1` to `m` there are in total `m * n * (k + 1)` assignments.

So the time complexity of this code is `O(m * n * (k + 1)) = O(mnk)`.